# CSS and border transparency around web map markers

Tags: web-mapping, cartography, css

The issue is that the image that I have in a web map visualizes map markers and place icons with white space around them.

[image]

I checked this in the FireFox browser developer console and it seems to be an issues with the background image/color being turned on. I click off the background image/color and the white space does indeed disappear but only in the browser developer console. I have attempted to modify my code in Brackets in just about every section to make the background color=transparent, but no luck. When I review the map in Google, there is no white space around images, just seems to be an issue with FireFox. I have opened the map in my smartphone as well as other devices and the white space remains. I have checked out help on www3 schools, but have been unable to resolve. Any thoughts?